# Why can't I call this list?

Tags: python, list, module

Im trying to import a list from a Module but its giving me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 8, in 
words_list = hangman_words.word_list()
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

here is my code:

```
#Step 5
import hangman_words
import hangman_art
import random

#TODO-1: - Update the word list to use the 'word_list' from hangman_words.py
#Delete this line: word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
words_list = hangman_words.word_list()
chosen_word = random.choice(words_list)
word_length = len(chosen_word)

end_of_game = False
lives = 6

#TODO-3: - Import the logo from hangman_art.py and print it at the start of the game.
print(hangman_art.logo)
#Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')

#Create blanks
display = []
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += "_"

while not end_of_game:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

    #TODO-4: - If the user has entered a letter they've already guessed, print the letter and let them know.
    if guess in display:
      print(f"You've already guessed {guess}")
    #Check guessed letter
    for position in range(word_length):
        letter = chosen_word[position]
        print(f"Current position: {position}\n Current letter: {letter}\n Guessed letter: {guess}")
        if letter == guess:
            display[position] = letter

    #Check if user is wrong.
    if guess not in chosen_word:
        #TODO-5: - If the letter is not in the chosen_word, print out the letter and let them know it's not in the word.
        print(f"You guessed {guess}, that is not in the word. You lose a (1) life")
        lives -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            end_of_game = True
            print("You lose.")

    #Join all the elements in the list and turn it into a String.
    print(f"{' '.join(display)}")

    #Check if user has got all letters.
    if "_" not in display:
        end_of_game = True
        print("You win.")

    #TODO-2: - Import the stages from hangman_art.py and make this error go away.
    print(hangman_art.stages[lives])
```

I tried putting it in a variable as you can see in my code but it resulted in the exact same error

Comment: What do you expect to get from *calling* the list?

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like you're trying to access hangman_words.word_list() as a function rather than a list. I believe you should just be able to remove the brackets to get:

```
words_list = hangman_words.word_list
```

I hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `hangman_words.word_list` is a `list`. Python lists are not callable, unlike functions.

### Alternative 1:

If your goal is to get a pointer to the list mentioned in `hangman_words`, you could do the following:

In `hangman_words.py`:

```
word_list = ['all', 'words', 'you', 'have']
```

In your script:

```
from hangman_words import word_list

print(word_list)
```

yields: `['all', 'words', 'you', 'have']`

### Alternative 2:

If you need to do something to your list, or want to make sure you don't change the original list, you could use a function to get a copy of the original list. Something like:

In `hangman_words.py`:

```
import copy
__word_list = ['all', 'words', 'you', 'have']

def get_word_list():
   return copy.deep_copy(__word_list)
```

In your script:

```
from hangman_words import get_word_list

print(get_word_list())
```

yields: `['all', 'words', 'you', 'have']`